# send_from_directory in Python Flask return 404 instead of cPanel (centos 7)

Tags: flask, cpanel

On my flask app, i can download my file from directory in static/assets/save/
i had tested on my local computer and it all works until i deployed to my server (centos 7).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/newIndex", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def newIndex():
    Appdata = extractApp(appUrl)
    json.dumps(Appdata)

    filename = Appdata["nama_file"].replace("./static/assets/save\\", "")
    permitted_directory = "static/assets/save/"  #I also try it using absolute path with '/home/../static/assets/downloads/' also does not works

    return send_from_directory(
        directory=permitted_directory, path=filename, as_attachment=True
    )

@app.route("/riwu")
def riwu():
    return "<h1>this is new page 123</h1>"
```

when deploy on Phusion Passenger in my cpanel, However the @app.route(“/”) it’s works also if i type manually in http://[my_website]/riwu it normally running. but not for @app.route(“/newIndex”).

it shows error :

"Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

I already setup the .htaccess and httpd.conf to change value from

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

But still does not work.

I’ve tried in my local server using Visual Code (Windows 10) and it’s works normally.

I would presume that the problem is in path permitted_directory = "static/assets/save/" ?

I would to tried to make endpoint ("/newIndex") is works as my local computer.